# Main image to appear in center

Tags: html, css

I am working on this page : 
http://tinyurl.com/ok9wzro

The main image (building) is shifted on left side.  I want it to be well aligned (in center) with content coming below.
I want it to be appear similar on all screen sizes.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks..

Sorry for the link, it is running on our intranet only. This is my code :

```
 <header style="background-image:none; background-size: none;background-color:#fff; height:410px;border-bottom:none" >
    <div style="width: 76%; margin: auto;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 8.5%;"></div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 83%; display: table;margin: 0 auto;">
            <img src="http://abcde.com/images/image.jpg" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto" width="" />   
            <div class="outer-wrapper" style="padding:6% 1% 1% 18%; position:absolute">
                     <div class="title" style="min-height: 0px; width: 66.15254%; position:absolute;margin-left:0px">
                        <hgroup>
                          % if homepage_overlay_html:
                            ${homepage_overlay_html}
                          % else:
                            % if self.stanford_theme_enabled():
                              <h1>${_("Free courses from <strong>{university_name}</strong>").format(university_name="VU")}</h1>
                            % else:
                              <h2>${_("Some text here")}</h2>
                            % endif
                              <h2>${_("For anyone, anywhere, anytime")}</h2>
                          % endif
                        </hgroup>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 8.5%;"></div>
        <br style="clear: left;" />
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: what are you getting on that page ?

Comment: this html with many style errors will not help us understand what you want. Create working fiddle at least, because you already gave us 2 404 ...

Answer (score 2):

Dont know what is your script..
I assumed and solution below.Hope it will helpful for you...

```
#imgeId
{
background:url(imagePath) no-repeat center center;
height:200px;
width:200px;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this its useful to you your
<p align="center"><img src="imgName.gif" alt="image description" height="100" width="100"></p>
```

Comment: Why is it useful?  Explain